# Delphi, how to call staticPortMapping

Tags: delphi, upnp

How can I call `StaticPortMapping` instead of `StaticPortMappingCollection` ?

Now I can call `StaticPortMappingCollection`, but I need methods from `StaticPortMapping`

```
Nat := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.NATUPnP');
Ports := Nat.StaticPortMappingCollection;
```

That code refer to [LINK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366147(v=vs.85).aspx)

I need Delphi code to refer : [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366145(v=vs.85).aspx)

Thank you.

Comment: Try '.Item' supplying the parameters in [getItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366151%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) possibly excluding the last one.

Comment: Thanks, but i need access to StaticPortMapping. Any ideas?

Comment: I presume you think I was commenting about something else. However that was my idea of getting a hold of a StaticPortMapping.

Comment: @Viruscom1000: the collection's `Item` property returns the `StaticPortMapping` object that you are looking for.  You pass in the desired port number and protocol as input, and it returns the associated `StaticPortMapping` object if found.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that. I wil try and i will write. Thanks again.